# Update data where ID match and use case to choose what data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have two tables

```
T1:
ID, Truck, Trailer
1   null   null
2   null   null

T2:
ID, Type, ResourceID 
1   R     111
1   F     222
1   D     333
2   R     444
2   F     555
```

I need a result where

```
ID, Truck, Trailer
1   111    222
2   444    555
```

How can I update `T1.Truck = T2.ResourceID` when `T2.Type = R` and `T1.Trailer = T2.ResourceID` when `T2.Type = F` where `T1.ID = T2.ID`.

This is what I have so far

```
UPDATE T1
    SET T1.Truck = CASE
    WHEN T2.Type = 'R' THEN T2.ResourceId
    ELSE T1.Truck
    END,
    T1.Trailer = CASE 
    WHEN T2.Type = 'F' THEN T2.ResourceId
                        ELSE T1.Trailer
                    END
    FROM T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, Type, ResourceId
                             FROM T2) T2
                              ON T1.Id = T2.Id
```

This will only Truck, but not trailer.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might want a `WHERE Type in ( 'R', 'F' )` somewhere to avoid processing the 'D' or any other types you don't care about. Not sure why you've added an extra layer of `SELECT` to your `INNER JOIN`, but that shouldn't cause a problem. Using an alias (`T2`) that matches a table name is a confusing choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current update query is that the update will update one column to null as it can't match both conditions at the same time.

If you did a `select *` instead of the update the result would look like:

```
ID  Truck   Trailer Id  Type    ResourceId
1   NULL    NULL    1   R       111 -- this will set R = 111  and F = null
1   NULL    NULL    1   F       222 -- this will set F = 222  and R = null
1   NULL    NULL    1   D       333 -- this will set R = null and F = null
2   NULL    NULL    2   R       444 -- this will set R = 444  and F = null
2   NULL    NULL    2   F       555 -- this will set R = null and F = 555
```

Here you can see that when `Type` matches `R` the update for `F` will update to `null` et cetera.

One solution is to join the `T2` table twice:

```
UPDATE T1
SET 
    T1.Truck = T2.ResourceId
    ,
    T1.Trailer = T3.ResourceId
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, ResourceId FROM T2 WHERE Type = 'R') T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, ResourceId FROM T2 WHERE Type = 'F') T3 ON T1.Id = T3.Id
```

If there might not always be both types (`R`,`F`) then use `left join` instead of `inner join` and check for `null` values.

Edit: thinking a bit more gives this query:

```
UPDATE T1
SET 
    T1.Truck   = ISNULL(T.rValue, T1.Truck),
    T1.Trailer = ISNULL(T.fValue, T1.Trailer)
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
       Id, 
       rValue = MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'R' THEN ResourceId END),
       fValue = MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'F' THEN ResourceId END)
    FROM T2 GROUP BY id
    ) T ON T1.Id = T.Id
```

On a side note: using an alias for a derived table that is also a table name can be pretty confusing and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

you can `PIVOT` the table `t2` before updating the `t1` table

Use the following query to pivot the `t2` table.

```
SELECT ID, R, F
FROM   t2
    PIVOT (Max(resourceID)
           FOR type IN ([R],[F]))pv
```

Now the result will in the format of `t1` table you can easily update using the following query

```
UPDATE A
SET    Trailer = F,
       Truck = R
FROM   t1 A
       INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, R, F
                   FROM   t2
                          PIVOT (Max(resourceID)
                                FOR type IN ([R],
                                             [F]))pv) B
               ON A.ID = b.ID
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/289b2/3)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `JOIN` with a condition for each case, so you would `JOIN` to `T2` twice. First on the `Id` and `[Type] = 'R'` and again, with `[Type] = 'F'`.

Here's some runnable sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (id INT, Truck INT, Trailer int)
CREATE TABLE #t2 (id INT, [Type] VARCHAR(1), ResourceId int)

INSERT INTO #t1
        ( id, Truck, Trailer )
VALUES (1, NULL, NULL),
       (2, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO #t2
        ( id, [Type], ResourceId )
VALUES  ( 1, 'R', 111),
        ( 1, 'F', 222),
        ( 1, 'D', 333),
        ( 2, 'R', 444),
        ( 2, 'F', 555)      

UPDATE #t1
SET Truck = TR.ResourceId, Trailer = TF.ResourceId
FROM #t1
INNER JOIN #t2 AS TR ON TR.id = #t1.id AND TR.[Type] = 'R'
INNER JOIN #t2 AS TF ON TF.id = #t1.id AND TF.[Type] = 'F'

SELECT * FROM #t1

DROP TABLE #t1
DROP TABLE #t2
```